# $n>1$ such that $x^n=e$ in a group implies $\exists m>1$ such that $x^m=x^{-1}$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ a group. Prove that if there exists an integer number $n\geq1$ such that $x^n=e$, then there must exist an integer number $m\geq1$ such that $x^m=x^{-1}$.

My solution:

1st case: if $o(x)=n$, then $x^n=e$ and $x^i\neq e$, for $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$. Since $x^{n-1}x=e \Rightarrow x^{n-1}=x^{-1}$. Now we choose $m=n-1$ so that x^m=x^{-1}$.

(edited) 2nd case: now let's consider $p \geq n$, then we can find integers $q$ and $m$ such that $p=nq+m$, with $0\leq m\leq n$ and we write
$$e=x^{nq+m}=(x^n)^qx^m=x^m$$

We may not have $m=0$, due to the minimality of $n$. So $m\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$ and we apply the last case.

What do you think?

Comment: Why not stop at $m=n-1$?

Comment: I think that the only thing to add after $m=n-1$ is "therefore we have $x^m=x^{-1}. Did I miss anything?

Comment: A good proof is clear on precisely what needs to be established. You seemed to correctly observe that $x^{n-1}=x^{-1}$. That answers the question already.  But, here in the OP your proof did not seem to recognize that this answered the question. [Your last full paragraph is word salad, and seems to not recognize that you already found your desired inverse.] And knowing where to end--that is a crucial part of a proof as well, and missing here. So I would say this as written here is incorrect [sorry]

Comment: I've made a few changes

Answer (score 1):

You do note that $x^{n-1}x = x^n=e=x^{-1}x$. Furthermore, in a group $G$, if the equation $ac=bc$ holds; $a,b,c \in G$, then so must also the equation $a=b$. Thus, setting $a=x^{n-1}$, $b=x^{-1}$, and $c=x$, it follows that $x^{n-1}=x^{-1}$ i.e., the inverse $x^{-1}$ of $x$ must be $x^{n-1}$.

Comment: It is not explicitly stated, but the 1st equation to the 2nd in my 2nd paragraph I used de definition of power and implication comes from the multiplication by $x^{-1)